# Issue with curl request for specific link

Tags: python, curl, urllib2

I'm doing some kind of analysis at Brasilian President Michel Temer, and I want to create a viz about the people he is meeting during the week.

But I don't know why I can't retrieve the data from the website.

I'm taking the data via Curl, and I already try urllib2 via python, and I got stuck in the request. This just stuck and get timeout.

This is what I'm doing:

The Link: https://www2.planalto.gov.br/acompanhe-planalto/agenda-do-presidente/agenda-do-presidente-michel-temer/2017-06-09?month:int=6&year:int=2017

My request:

`curl https://www2.planalto.gov.br/acompanhe-planalto/agenda-do-presidente/agenda-do-presidente-michel-temer/2017-06-09?month:int=6&year:int=2017 --insecure`

I add a verbose to see what is happening:

```
*   Trying 170.246.252.230...
* Connected to www2.planalto.gov.br (170.246.252.230) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /home/t****/anaconda2/ssl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=BR; O=ICP-Brasil; OU=PR-DITEC; OU=Autoridade Certificadora da Presidencia da Republica; CN=www2.planalto.gov.br
*  start date: Dec 23 19:31:39 2016 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 23 19:31:39 2017 GMT
*  issuer: C=BR; O=ICP-Brasil; OU=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2; CN=Autoridade Certificadora da Presidencia da Republica v4
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> GET /acompanhe-planalto/agenda-do-presidente/agenda-do-presidente-michel-temer/2017-06-08?month:int=6&year:int=2017 HTTP/1.1
> Host: www2.planalto.gov.br
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 110
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 110
```

Is there a way to get this information? Or a solution?

Comment: Just using telnet gets me a page that says "Access denied! This transaction was rejected because it possibly violates the information security policy of the Presidency of the Republic.
Contact your system administrator for more information." - perhaps some combination of User-Agent or other header is needed?

Comment: The server has very poor SSL support: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www2.planalto.gov.br

Comment: @SimonFraser you Were Right! I added the User-Agent and it Worked! Please add the response for me to give you the answer and upvote.